# how to do on the Angular svg map to bubble point?

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I added this map for the angular type script project, dose any one know to how to create bubble count region on the map like this image

[Stack blitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ea5uwb?file=src/app/app.component.html)

[here the jsFiddle code link](https://jsfiddle.net/phwar4vd/)

[image: mage description here]

**css here**

```
p {font-size: 12px}

#core {
  fill: #ff4f81;
  animation: pulse1 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
}

#radar  {
  fill: #F99EAD;
  animation: pulse2 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }

  30% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(2);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(2);
  }
}

@keyframes pulse2 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
    opacity: 0;
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(6, 6);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
.row-wrap {
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.row-middle {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #0E76FE;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.row-middle-two{
  font-size: 17px;color: #808490;
}
.row-middle-three{
  font-size: 14px;color: #9DA2AE;
}
.row-bottom-small{
  font-size: 10px; color: #B9C0CD;
}.row-top-small{
   font-size: 10px;
  color: #B9C0CD;
 }
.row-bottom{
  color: #A3A9B5;font-size: 12px;
}
.row-top{
color: #A3A9B5;font-size: 12px;
}
p {font-size: 12px}
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what is your problem / what is your goal? it's a bit unclear to me

Comment: @GuyNachshon Hi look at my map https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ea5uwb?file=src/app/app.component.html   I wanna to  know how to do my attached image like bubble points on the map

Comment: yeah, that's the part I understood. but where would you get the number from? Do you want to add them conditionally? etc

Comment: @GuyNachshon Number  get my API, I can handle but  issue on the UI part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to add an `SVG` bubble to your map (which is also `SVG`), you first need to pick the SVG file you'd like to add.

I chose the following (run the fiddle to see how it looks):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

<svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 293.334 293.334" style="enable-background:new 0 0 293.334 293.334;" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
    <g>
        <path style="fill:#010002;" d="M146.667,0C94.903,0,52.946,41.957,52.946,93.721c0,22.322,7.849,42.789,20.891,58.878
            c4.204,5.178,11.237,13.331,14.903,18.906c21.109,32.069,48.19,78.643,56.082,116.864c1.354,6.527,2.986,6.641,4.743,0.212
            c5.629-20.609,20.228-65.639,50.377-112.757c3.595-5.619,10.884-13.483,15.409-18.379c6.554-7.098,12.009-15.224,16.154-24.084
            c5.651-12.086,8.882-25.466,8.882-39.629C240.387,41.962,198.43,0,146.667,0z M146.667,144.358
            c-28.892,0-52.313-23.421-52.313-52.313c0-28.887,23.421-52.307,52.313-52.307s52.313,23.421,52.313,52.307
            C198.98,120.938,175.559,144.358,146.667,144.358z"/>
        <circle style="fill:#010002;" cx="146.667" cy="90.196" r="21.756"/>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

---

since you have already had everything set up beside the bubbles, and I didn't want to change it, I added a transform attribute to the `<g>` (so the bubble will be at the exact points and scale)

```
transform="translate(-64 -126) scale(0.5)"
```

---

To add it to the map, you just need to insert it in the location groups that you'd like and change the translate parameters so that it is in the right spot.

you can see it in work [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zqxbnk?file=src/app/app.component.html) (stackbitz)